# update mssql set date in Perl file

Tags: sql-server, perl

I want to set date in mssql from Perl file.
Here is my code:

```
my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime();         
my $sql = $dbh->prepare("update BlastDatabaseDim set Databasedate = ? DatabaseVersion = ? where DatabaseName = ?");
$sql->execute($date,$DatabaseVersion,$db_name);
```

What is the problem with this code?

I got this error:

```
Can't Execute Command 'update BlastDatabaseDim set Databasedate = ? DatabaseVersion = ? where DatabaseName = ?'
Description : Incorrect syntax near 'DatabaseVersion'.
```

Comment: Please don't post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308862/cant-execute-command-update-in-perl-file) multiple times.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a comma between

```
Databasedate = ? DatabaseVersion = ?
```

Should be

```
Databasedate = ? ,DatabaseVersion = ?
```

Comment: OMG! That's it. I spent 5 hours trying solve it. Many many thanks.

Comment: No worries, I miss the simple stuff all the time too, sometimes helps to get another set of eyes on something.

Comment: Rather than marking code in bold, you should use [Markdown code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)